# Does Politics.SE deals only with US Politics?

Tags: discussion

Is this proposal deals only with US Politics? Most of the questions only fits into that category.

And if this is the case, shouldn't it be more appropriately named? Something like "US Politics" or "American Politics"?

Comment: Should we rename StackOverflow.com to StackOverflow_C#.com?  or StackOverflow.NET?

Comment: Interesting. Yes, if it only deals with those technologies then we should. But it's not the case. And similarly it's not the case with Politics.SE. That was the question.

Answer (score 7):

We desperately want more non-US questions. I'm still waiting on an answer to my question about Nepal, for example we also have questions about Kashmir, about BJP and Congress- please ask more nonUS!

Comment: Alright! Can we have a country specific tags in the questions to remove confusion and increase clarity?

Comment: We have them.  Try the 'India' tag for example - http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india

Comment: @AffableGeek - [me too](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/641/what-causes-a-change-in-bo-xilais-affiliations-from-elitists-to-populists)!